# When updating an Oracle table from C#, sometimes the change gets made and sometimes 0 rows get affected

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, parameters

Im creating a tool at my job that allows me to update directly some values in the database. Here is the piece of code that works like a charm. I created the connection and the command at a global level.

```
private void btnChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(cbxGroupsList.SelectedIndex != -1 && cbxLanguages.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    //Creating Parameters
                    command.Parameters.Add("p_Languages", cbxLanguages.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(1, 5));
                    command.Parameters.Add("p_Group", cbxGroupsList.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    //Creating the query with the previously created parameters
                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE USERS SET LANG = :p_Language WHERE USER_ID = :p_Group";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    //Executing the update comand
                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //If there are no problems, update the status label
                    UpdateStatusBar(rowsAffected);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    lblStatus.Content = error;
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
            }

        }
```

This code executes as expected. The record gets updated and the ExecuteNonQuery() function brings a value of 1.

The problem is that when executing the following code, the ExecutenonQuery() function brings back a value of 0, meaning the data wasnt updted. (it was not updated, I checked directly in the database).

```
private void btnChangeGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Clearing the status label
            ClearStatusMessage();

            //Making sure the values are not empty
            if ((txtEmpID.Text != "" || txtEmpID.Text == "EMP ID...") && cbxGroups.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                try
                {
                    //PARAMETERS== name of parameter, parameter data type, parameter value, direction of parameter. 
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.Add("p_EmpID", txtEmpID.Text);
                    command.Parameters.Add("p_UserID", cbxGroups.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    //Creating the query with the previously created parameters

                    command.CommandText ="UPDATE WEB_ACCESS SET USER_ID = :p_UserID WHERE EMP_ID = :p_EmpID";
                    //Executing the update comand
                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //If there are no problems, update the status label
                    UpdateStatusBar(rowsAffected);


                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    lblStatus.Content = error;
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Content = "Do not leave anything blank please";
            }
        }
```

As you can see, Im doing exactly the same in both buttons. The only way I got the second button to work as I expected was passing the values directly to the string with a string.Format() function

```
command.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE WEB_ACCESS SET USER_ID = '{0}' WHERE EMP_ID = '{1}'", cbxGroups.SelectedItem.ToString(), txtEmpID.Text);
```

I have tried multiple things and I cannot get it to work passing the parameters as I would like.
Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Edited session:
Notice how I ordered the parameters declaration

```
 private void btnUnlockAccount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClearStatusMessage();

            string hashForPwA = "E1-62-52-39-EB-68-DE-75-DD-49";

            if (txtUnlockEmpID.Text != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Parameters.Clear();

                    //Creating Parameters
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_UserPass", hashForPwA));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Access", "A"));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_EmpID",txtUnlockEmpID.Text));
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    //Creating the query with the previously created parameters
                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE WEB_ACCESS SET USER_PASS = :p_UserPass, ACCESS_STATUS = :p_Access WHERE USER_ID = :p_EmpID";


                    //Executing the update comand
                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //If there are no problems, update the status label
                    UpdateStatusBar(rowsAffected);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    lblStatus.Content = error;
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont think even your 1st example will run because of typo error. `Add("p_Languages",`. Look at the parameter name having one extra `s`. Now, coming to problem with 2nd. What is data type of `EMP_ID`?

Comment: weridly enough it was running witout problems. But you were right there was a typo, I fixed it and it still works fine. Now im very confused... and about EMP_ID, its just a string (varchar2)

Comment: The name isn't used when parsing parameters, it uses them in the order they are added to the array.  You are setting Emp ID first in the parameter array but asking for it as the second parameter.  Think of the parameter placeholders as :1, :2, etc and order them appropriately.  This I think is why the first works with the typo.

Comment: @DominicCotton I tried ordering the creation of the parameters and still doesn't work. Please check the post, I added a new code snippet showing the changes.

Comment: @DominicCotton Actually, the scenario you were refering too does work now but trying the same technique on the edited part of the post didnt work. Any ideas?